# Por que um número inteiro não formata corretamente (Kotlin/Java)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Eu uso o *Android Studio 3.4.2*. Executei um código de teste que gera um formato muito estranho. Esse trecho foi colocado logo depois do início do `onCreate`. E trata-se de um número inteiro puro!

```
fmtFloat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##############")   
fmtFloat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING)
Log.d("myMess", fmtFloat.format("98765432".toDouble()))
```

A imagem do `logCat` é

[image: LogCat]

Quando eu rodo essa expressão na janela de avaliação, ocorre o mesmo problema:

[image: Evaluate Window]

Entretanto, quando  rodo o MESMO código como um teste no desktop no *Android Studio*, nenhum erro aparece.

```
98.765.432
```

No [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org) também funciona OK.

Porque isso acontece no  *Android* app e não acontece no Desktop? Qual a diferença?

Como se trata de uma  biblioteca *Java*, coloquei o tag do *Java* na pergunta, além de *Kotlin*.

Debugging o app Android app, Eu rodei na janela de avaliação de expressão:

```
"98765432".toDouble()==98765432.0
```

Sim, é verdadeiro, claro!

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**
Quando se usa o modo de arredondamento default (HALF_EVEN) parar *Decimal Format*, o app passa a funcionar normalmente no Android, aceitando até 14 dígitos (Que eu escolhi por segurança) antes de iniciar exibir o número em formato exponencial. Assim segue o mistério ...

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 2**
Meu número que usa o modo de arredondamento `Ceiling` no método format method da variável `Decimal Format` é um `Double`, que tem  [64 bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh3pk.png) com 53 bits para mantissa. Seria, desse modo, capaz de armazenar corretamente números até 16 dígitos e meu número tem apenas 8 dígitos!

[image: Java double]

Comment: Talvez seja diferença de locale. Qual locale vc recebe quando vc roda `Locale.getDefault()` nesses diferentes ambientes?

Comment: Leonardo, aqui `Pt-Br` mesmo. Eu consigo mudar o local programaticamente e isso não interfere. Eu já testei.